# Automatically transfer data regardless of Schema Changes

Tags: database, etl, database-schema

There is an OLTP DB that keeps on changing. Since it is a busy DB, the data is transferred to another DB using SSIS. Any change to OLTP leads to an impact to SSIS. Is there any process/tech that can transfer the data from one DB to another regardless of DB Schema changes. Not looking at replication or restoring the back ups, talking about huge DBs.